# Geeting error Invalid or Corrupt Jar file error for cmdrunner-2.2.jar in jmeter

Tags: terminal, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to install JMeter and its plugins using the terminal. Below are the commands for it. I am getting the error at the last step.
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile ./../lib/cmdrunner-2.2.jar

```
wget https://downloads.apache.org//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.5.tgz
tar zxvf apache-jmeter-5.5.tgz
cd apache-jmeter-5.5/lib/
curl -O http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.3/cmdrunner-2.3.jar
cd ext/
curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.7/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar
cd ../../bin
java -cp ../lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
PluginsManagerCMD.sh available
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if `PluginsManagerCMD.sh` wants to have `cmdrunner-2.2.jar` why you're trying to feed `cmdrunner-2.3.jar` to it?

The most straightforward solution would be changing this line:

```
curl -O http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.3/cmdrunner-2.3.jar
```

to this one:

```
curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar
```

Also you need to change the download URL for the plugins manager itself:

```
curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.7/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar
```

If you want you can report the inconsistency via [JMeter Plugins support forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins)

More information:

- [Plugins Manager from Command-Line](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)
- [How to Install the JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

I would also change JMeter download URL to `https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.5.tgz` as getting version 5.5 from the `downloads.apache.org` might stop working when next release will be published.

Comment: I have used ```cmdrunner-2.2.jar``` but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Updated the answer with correct URLs

Comment: Worked after changing the urls.